# After rebooting into Acronis and back, mouse cursor doesn't move

Tags: windows-7, mouse

Win7 Pro. I rebooted into Acronis True Image, done disk work, rebooted back into OS, and now mouse cusror doens't move from center of monitor. Why. It works ok in BIOS UI. I didn't disable devices in bios.

Comment: How long did you wait in Windows before you decided it was never going to move again?  Did you try another reboot?  Did you try it in a different port? Does it work as expected in Windows' Safe Mode?

Comment: Tks for hint!! solved with another usb port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: USB mouse: I plugged it into another port, Win7 found new device, installed, and now mouse moves again.